# Where are Visual Studio For Mac Snippets Stored?

Tags: monodevelop, visual-studio-mac

I'm wanting to create a bunch of snippets for Visual Studio on my macbook and back them up (or move them to another mac).

I find a directory in my home called Visual Studio 2017 as shown in picture but all the directories are empty (even after I created my own snippet and exited VS).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio Mac User-defined Snippets location:

```
~/Library/VisualStudio/7.0/Snippets
```

Note: This from your home dir (`~`)

Within there you will find your snippets as xml files, the name starts with the id that you assigned the snippet, i.e.:

```
se.template.xml
```